# How to Vuex state with a getter within a module from another module

Tags: vue.js, module, vuex, getter

I am building a application in VueJS however Vuex modules are giving me some problems.

What ever I try I am not able to retrieve the state in a module when calling it from another module.

In my Vue Devtools Vuex getters:
modA/mycustomer: is undefined

I have read all documentation at the Vuex website and tried some of the solutions already given in stackoverflow but I am lost. Probably overlooking something

my store.js

```
  export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      modA: moduleA,
      modB: moduleB
    }
  })
```

moduleA JS

```
  export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state:{
       customerId:0
    },
    getters: {
       customerId: state => {
          return state.customerId
       }      
    }
  }
```

moduleB.js

```
   export default {
     namespaced: true,
     state:{
       orderId:0
    },
     getters: {
       orderId: state => {
          return state.orderId
       },
       mycustomer: rootGetters => {
          return rootGetters['modA/customerId']
       }
     }
  }
```

I would normally expect to get the customerId with this request. But only have undefined
Some states are needed across modules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relevant documentation is [Accessing Global Assets in Namespaced Modules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#accessing-global-assets-in-namespaced-modules) where it says:

> If you want to use global state and getters, `rootState` and `rootGetters` are passed as the **3rd and 4th arguments to getter functions**, and also exposed as properties on the context object passed to action functions.

So if you want to access the `customerId` getter of the `modA` module inside the `mycustomer` getter in the `modB` module, it should be:

```es6
mycustomer(state, getters, rootState, rootGetters) {
  return rootGetters['modA/customerId']
}
```

Comment: Thank now I know what I was missing. My mistake to only take one argument. It has solved the problem. Great Job!

Comment: doesn't the function need to be called? Otherwise you're just returning the getter function

Comment: @Emobe No, you do not call getters, they are reigstered using `Object.defineProperty` and so they're just properties.